# Depth First Search on graph using Iterator

Tags: java, graph, depth-first-search

I'm trying to make this into a Depth First Search. At first it was in Breadth First and now I'm trying to convert it. I've been working on this for DAYS and have tried multiple different things.

```
        import java.util.*;


class Graph{
class Edge{
    int v,w;
    public Edge(int v,int w){
        this.v=v; this.w=w;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "("+v+","+w+")";
    }
}
List<Edge> G[];
public Graph(int n){
    G=new LinkedList[n];
    for(int i=0;i<G.length;i++)
        G[i]=new LinkedList<Edge>();
}
boolean isConnected(int u,int v){
    for(Edge i: G[u])
        if(i.v==v) return true;
    return false;
}
void addEdge(int u,int v,int w)
{

    G[u].add(0,new Edge(v,w));
    G[v].add(0,new Edge(u,w));
}
public int getWeight(int u, int v)
{
    for (Edge e : G[u]) 
    {
    if (e.v == v) 
        {
             return e.w ;
        }
    }throw new NoSuchElementException();
}
@Override
public String toString(){
    String result="";
    for(int i=0;i<G.length;i++)
        result+=i+"=>"+G[i]+"\n";
    return result;
}
```

// here's the problem though

```
   void DFS(int s)
{

    boolean visited[] = new boolean[G.length];

    LinkedList<Integer> stack = new LinkedList<Integer>();


    stack.push(s);

    while (stack.size() != 0)
    {

        s = stack.pop();
        System.out.print(s+" ");



        Iterator<Edge> i = G[s].listIterator();
         if (!visited[s])
            {
                visited[s] = true;

                 while (i.hasNext())
                 {
                    int n = i.next().v;
                    stack.push(n);


                 }

            }

    }
}

}

    public class GraphEx
    {
      public static void main(String[] args) 
   {    
      Graph g=new Graph(10);
      g.addEdge(1,2,38);
      g.addEdge(1,5 ,19);
      g.addEdge(1,3 ,35);
      g.addEdge(1,4 ,11);
      g.addEdge(4,3,27);
      g.addEdge(3,6,13);
      g.addEdge(3,5,28);
      g.addEdge(5,6,26);



    System.out.println(g);

    System.out.println("\nDFS");
    g.DFS(1);
```

This prints out:
DFS
1 2 1 5 1 3 1 4 1 3 6 3 5 5 6 3 4

That would be perfect if the first part didn't have the ones inserted for all the print numbers after 2 and then ended after 6. This is the closest output to what I think I should be getting I've gotten out of all the code I've written so I posted this.

EDIT: Here's the original that I'm trying to reconvert

```
        void BFS(int s)
{
    // Mark all the vertices as not visited(By default
    // set as false)
    boolean visited[] = new boolean[G.length];

    // Create a queue for BFS
    LinkedList<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    // Mark the current node as visited and enqueue it
    visited[s]=true;
    queue.add(s);

    while (queue.size() != 0)
    {
        // Dequeue a vertex from queue and print it
        s = queue.poll();
        System.out.print(s+" ");

        // Get all adjacent vertices of the dequeued vertex s
        // If a adjacent has not been visited, then mark it
        // visited and enqueue it
        Iterator<Edge> i = G[s].listIterator();
        while (i.hasNext())
        {
            int n = i.next().v;
            if (!visited[n])
            {
                visited[n] = true;
                queue.add(n);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DFS is an algorithm that is usually run on trees which do not have cycles or links back to their parents. This causes two pretty simple problems for your graph implementation. Problem 1 is that each vertex you have points back to it's "parent". For example, vertex 1 has an edge to vertex 2, and vertex 2 has an edge to vertex 1. When edge 2 is visited, all of it's children are put onto the stack. When this happens, you are putting vertex 1, which has been visited already, back onto the stack. Issue 2 is that sometimes you have vertices pushed onto the stack multiple times before they're visited. For example, vertices 5 and 3 both add 6 to the stack before 6 is visited. One way to quickly fix both of these problems is to do this:

```
  while (stack.size() != 0)
    {
        s = stack.pop();
        if(visited[s]) //add these two lines
                continue; 
        System.out.print(s+" ");
        Iterator<Edge> i = G[s].listIterator();
        if (!visited[s])
            {
                visited[s] = true;
                while (i.hasNext())
                {
                   int n = i.next().v;
                   stack.push(n);
                }
            }

    }
```

If you check the element popped off of the stack to see if it has been visited, you will remove both vertices which are parents that have already been visited, and nodes that have been pushed onto the stack multiple times by their parents. Simply check to see if a vertex has been visited, and if it has just continue with the next iteration of the loop.